# Getting started with Cascading

Tags: cascading

Can someone please advise me on how to get started with Cascading.

The problem is I have no knowledge of Java or the object oriented programming principles although I personally started learning Scala recently. I know that Scalding will be a better choice for me but the team I'll be joining is using Cascading and I have to learn that.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Update: Thank you for the answers. We have moved on from Cascading to Spark for the data processing needs.

Comment: [Cascading for the Impatient](http://docs.cascading.org/impatient/) is a good starting point.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to learn Java and OOP principles. Adapting OOP in your code takes time. I am not a great coder but i try implementing them.
Regarding Cascading, there are few material that you can follow.

I started learning cascading reading this: [Cascading User Guide](http://docs.cascading.org/cascading/2.2/userguide/htmlsingle/)

, Casacing.learn on github

and Cascading for the impatient

There are some books for learning Cascading

1. Learning Cascading by Michael Covert
2. Enterprise Data Workflows with Cascading by Paco Nathan

Other materials

cascading.org/documentation/tutorials/

OR

cascadingorg.405dev.com/documentation/tutorials/

If you want to search for something, [ProgramCreek][5] is a good resource

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @WhatisThatException, Cascading user Guide is one of the best documentation for Cascading. Besides that following are the few links where you can find other tutorials.

1. Cascading official tutorials: http://www.cascading.org/documentation/tutorials/
2. Cascading for the Impatient: http://docs.cascading.org/impatient/
3. Cascading.Learn: https://github.com/BertrandDechoux/cascading.learn
4. Google group where developers ask specific questions about their issues and Chris Wensel (Cascading author) provides answers to them: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/cascading-user
5. Tutorial with a simple example (blog): http://blog.matthewrathbone.com/2015/06/25/real-world-hadoop-implementing-a-left-outer-join-in-java-with-cascading.html
6. Youtube channel for Cascading: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC_1fvA0H60rj68uDvm1gRxQ

Hope this might help.

Answer (score 0):

Cascading is an abstraction over MapReduce. If you understand the basics of MR then it would not be much difficult for you to understand Cascading also. For getting started you can refer to Cascading official [documentation](http://www.cascading.org/documentation/). 
It is pretty good, with the API level details which will help you understand the basics better. If you are looking for some in-depth implementation level detail of cascading and comparison of cascading with raw MapReduce, then you can also refer to this [blog](https://tech.flipkart.com/expressing-etl-workflows-via-cascading-192eb5e7d85d).